# Google data Studio REGEX_MATCH - How to extract string from between strings?

Tags: regex, looker-studio, re2

I have a url which is as follows

`www.abc.com?utm_term=stack%20overflow&device=mobile`

I need to extract  `stack%20overflow` from with the url. I have tried everything but it doesn't work. Any help is appreciated.

I tried the following it doesn't work
`REGEXP_EXTRACT(URL, "utm_term=\\w+/([\\w-]+)/")`

Comment: What do you mean with "between `stack%20overflow`"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to achieve it with something like `utm_term=([^&]*)` which will get every character in between `utm_term=` and `&`.

Example:

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(URL, 'utm_term=([^&]*)')
```